# Csv headers mapping issue in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, druid

I had a csv file, and in one csv file I'm getting 10 headers and in another l'm getting 15 headers. Like this, I have a number of csv files, all of which are related, but the only thing is that the headers are dynamic.Now I have to map the headers and ingest the csv file in druid. Is this possible. I have tried using evaluatejson processor,attributetojson,replace text processors it is not working, for fixed headers is working but for me getting dynamic headers.

I have to map the dynamic headers and store the csv file into druid using nifi processors.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update the Druid table to match the columns in the CSV file (presuming the 15-column one over the 10-column one)? If so I'd try using the [Druid JDBC driver](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql-jdbc.html) and UpdateDatabaseTable to add the extra columns and then PutDatabaseRecord to put the data into the table. If I've misunderstood your use case, please let me know and I'll help where I can.